# Is there a way to initialize EII property within constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization, explicit-interface

Let's start with code from MS page:

```
interface ILeft
{
    int P { get;}
}
interface IRight
{
    int P();
}

class Middle : ILeft, IRight
{
    public int P() { return 0; }
    int ILeft.P { get { return 0; } }
}
```

I would like to change `Middle` in such way, the EII property is once initialized, something like this:

```
class Middle : ILeft, IRight
{
    public int P() { return 0; }
    int ILeft.P { get; }

    Middle()
    {
        ILeft.P = 0;    
    }
}
```

Above code does not compile, thus my question -- is there a **syntax** for doing this?

*I am asking about syntax, because brute force way would be to declare private field and redirect `ILeft.P` getter to return data from it.*

Comment: In short - there is no such syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only other possibility besides your suggested approach of using a backing field rather than an auto-property is to use the property initializer syntax, e.g.:

```
int ILeft.P { get; } = 0;
```

Of course with this you can't initialize based on, say, an argument passed to the constructor, so it provides only limited additional flexibility.

(There is a *proposal* to add "[primary constructors](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/primary-constructors.md)" to the C# language, which *might* make it possible to initialize a get-only explicitly implemented  interface property based on a constructor argument, though as far as I know there's no timeline for its inclusion in the language so I wouldn't hold your breath...)